# How to set .htaccess so link in side html file will read from a base directory

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess

Right now, I have put my html files under `public/views` folder,
libraries under `public/libs`, and customized files in `public/src`

I am using the `DictoryIndex` to set the default home page. Like `DirectoryIndex public/views/index.html`

but inside the `index.html` file, I have to use `<a href="public/views/product.html"></a>` to open the file under the same directory as the `index.html`, otherwise it could not find the file. And then the URL will look ugly, like `site.com/public/views/product.html`.

Can I ask, how could I set the `.htaccess` file to get rid of the `public/views` in the URL address?

One more question, when i write the code to import the libraries in `index.html`, it seems like it will read from the base folder (like where I put the `.htaccess` file). But in the other html files, they will read from their own directory, like the html file in `public/view` will start to read from folder `views`. Is there anyway to solve this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to access your libs and custom files through HTTP too? If not, just set your document root to `public/views`

Otherwise, you could rewrite `*.html` to `public/views` using something like

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule (.+\.html)$ /public/views/$1 [L]
```

Anyway, using a fullpath instead of just a filename in the `DirectoryIndex` directive is not a good idea, for obvious reasons.

It also solves your second issue. For now, `public/views/index.html` is considered as `/` so anything relative to this file is relative to `/`, not the `views` folder. On the other hand, any other file is still considered as "itself", therefore includes are relative to the `views` folder.

Comment: it did not work, it only gives me the list of folders and files in the root folder... Btw i am using wamp and localhost testing the code, could it be a problem?

Comment: Make sure you have the `AllowOverride All` option in the correct `Directory` directive of your main Apache conf. Without it, you won't be able to use all the functionalities of your `.htaccess`. I also made my answer more robust. Look for `AllowOverride` in `httpd.conf` and change it from `None` to `All` in the correct `Directory` block. You could optionally add a new `Directory` block pointing to your document root to be more specific.

Comment: Hi it works, but the url shows "/public/views", is there anyway to remove it?

Comment: It didn't when I tested it on my local server, and that's the whole point of rewrite rules, it' rewritten, not redirected. Could you post your full `.htaccess`?

Comment: my .htaccess only contains the code you wrote, I copied and pasted it... But i dont have httpd.conf in my root folder yet. I am using wamp, do I edit in their httpd.conf file, or do i make a new one to put inside the root of my project folder? If I need to make a new one... do you mind to give me a sample or a link of tutorial you think you will helpful? thanks :-)

Comment: You'll need to edit theirs. Putting an httpd.conf file in your project wouldn't do anything.

Comment: sorry it still does not work. I have made a copy in JsFiddle, and put the code there, could you take a look? Thanks a lot. https://jsfiddle.net/x69chen/y5xw3m26/

Comment: You have `AllowOverride All` in `/` so it's fine.
Make sure you restart Apache and empty your cache before testing again.